# Acessar elementos HTML dentro de um componente Angular

Tags: html, angular, component

Tenho um dashboard:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<div style="display: flex; height: 90vh;">
  <app-sidebar id="sidebar" class="hide"></app-sidebar>

  <app-funil></app-funil>

</div>
```

e dentro desse dashboard, eu chamo minha sidebar (que também é um componente), e o componente 'app-funil'.

Até aí tudo bem, mas dentro do funil, tenho um botão, que tem o efeito de fazer a sidebar aparecer e desaparecer, e preciso acessar esse botão que está dentro do funil através do TS do dashboard, mas não estou conseguindo.

Esse é meu TS do dashboard, com a função para fazer a sidebar aparecer e desaparecer:

```
  handleShowSidebar() {
    document.getElementById('showSidebar').addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('hide')
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.handleShowSidebar();
  }
```

Comment: Caro Arthur em Angular e semelhantes Seria melhor controlar as classes pelo ngClass, ao invés de refazer o que existe pronto, até mesmo o evento click seria melhor controlado no proprio (click)= que já existe na estrutura do Angular.... me parece que sua intenção de controlar via JS puro talvez seja por inexeriencia com Angular, o que torna isto um problema de [XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635) PS: o downvote não é meu.

Comment: não vejo o porque utilizar o ngClass, pois não são mesmos componentes: Nesse caso, eu tenho 3 (Dashboard, Funil e Sidebar), preciso pegar DENTRO do funil, o click do botão, e fazer com que DENTRO do Dashboard, ele faça o componente Sidebar sumir...

Comment: Caro Arthur ngClass, click, ngFor, ngIf funcionam com o seu HTML, não precisa nada ser componente, como eu disse, acho q na verdade vc ainda não entendeu bem o Angular e por isso esta reinventando a roda para um recurso que ja existe no angular.

Comment: Sim querido, mas é necessário que seja componente, pois esse 'funil' será trocado por outro componente, assim que clicar na sidebar, portanto, a solução não pode vir do HTML...

Comment: blz, eu tentei explicar, vou tentar dizer de outra forma, vc esta tentando fazer algo que dá pra fazer diretamente no Angular, irá disparar o mesmo evento, o que você tem que aprender é como funciona o ngClass com variaveis e até IFs dentro da propria sintaxe do angular ou do objeto da classe pertencente ao "template" especifico. Acredite, dá pra fazer tudo isso sem precisar ficar fazendo na mão a parte do evento e seleção de elementos.

Comment: Arthur dá uma pesquisada em **@Input** e **@Output** que fazem a comunicação entre componentes  no Angular o primeiro vc passa valores do componente pai(dashboard) pro filho(funil) e o segundo emite valores do filho pro pai.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui utilizar Input e Output do Angular para resolver esse problema, ai invés de passar a referencia de um botão, eu passei o evento do click, desta maneira:

TS do Funil (Filho):

```
  @Input() showSidebar: boolean = false;

  @Output() situationSidebar = new EventEmitter();

  onClick() {
    this.showSidebar = !this.showSidebar;
    this.situationSidebar.emit({ situation: this.showSidebar })
  }
```

com o botão:

```
<button class="buttons" id="showSidebar" (click)="onClick()">Menu</button>
```

e chamando isso no componente Dashboard (Pai):

```
onChangeSidebar() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('hide')
}
```

com o HTML:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<div style="display: flex; height: 90vh;">
  <app-sidebar id="sidebar" class="hide"></app-sidebar>

  <app-funil (situationSidebar)="onChangeSidebar()"></app-funil>

</div>
```

Comment: Boa é isso aí, tentando e aprendendo sempre!